# Does faking life help to brighten one's aura?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

In the description of Aura Perception [Auspex 2] it is mentioned that the Aura of a Kindred looks pale in comparison to one of a mortal.

Would faking life help in "masking" that fact?

Or is it impossible to "fake" one's aura?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, burning blood does not affect a vampire's aura.**

Burning blood does not affect your aura; it only affects your physical appearance. You need a discipline or ritual to change your aura. An example is *Obfuscate 2: Mask of Tranquility* which hides predator's taint.